# Jumping to *just before* the nth occurence?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions

I can use `f` or `F` to highlight/change or jump to the next occurrence of say, a comma.

This is way useful, but is there a way to highlight/change to the character just before?

---

Say I have some code:

```
this.remove (object, index + 1, name)
                     ^ cursor
```

and want to replace the `index + 1` with `location`?  `cf,` will require me to retype the comma `location,` in my replacement text.

---

Is there a command already to do this, or how would I go about adding this to my Vim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have scrolled a bit when you read `:help f`:

```
ct,
cT,
```

See `:help t`.

Comment: Another great shortcut I've found is `;` repeats the last `f` `F` `t` `T` command used.